# Does Clojure have variable references?

Tags: pointers, clojure

I'm trying to implement a neural net, and each neuron needs a reference to other neurons.  I've been trying to implement this reference through atoms.

Consider the code

```
(def neuron1 {:connections [(atom 0)])
(def neuron2 {:connections [(atom neuron1)]})

(update-in neuron1 [:connections 0] #(reset! % neuron2))
```

That last will blow the stack.

As such, it seems that an atom *contains* its contents, rather than just *referencing* them.

What do I do if I want to pass around the equivalent of a pointer?  Do I have to use a function, as in

```
(def neuron1 {:connections [(fn [] neuron2)]})
```

and call it, rather than using an atom and dereferencing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine. The reason that you're blowing the stack is that you're running the update-in command at the REPL, *which causes it to print the result*. Since each neuron is nested within the other, the print statement encounters a stack overflow. Try encasing the update-in command within another statement, such as (type), or run it within another function.

Answer (score 3):

WolfeFan has already answered the part of question "why the stackoverflow". 
As far as pointer/reference kind of feature is concerned you can store the var (which is bound to the neuron) in the atom rather then the neuron object itself. Also, I would suggest to make the connection an atom of vectors rather than individual connections as atoms as most probably you will be modifying the connections object from multiple threads.

Example:

```
(def neuron1 {:connections (atom [])})
(def neuron2 {:connections (atom [#'neuron1])})

(update-in neuron1 [:connections] #(swap! % conj #'neuron2))
```

When you need to fetch a connected neuron you need to use `var-get`:

```
(-> neuron1 :connections deref (get 0) var-get)
```

Vars are themselves thread safe, to change the root binding of a var you need to use `alter-var-root` which is an atomic operation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use simple Clojure data structures it's probably best to forget fine-grained use of atoms. Instead, make a huge map to represent the whole network, maybe like:

```
(def ann {1 {:connections [1 2 3] :weights [0.1 -0.3 0.5] :state 0.3} 2 {:connections [1 2 3] :weights [0.1 -0.3 0.5] :state 0.13} 3 {:connections [2 3] :weights [0.5 0.2] :state 0.31}})
```

Then reduce over it, using update-in etc to update the nodes. Make all your update functions to take immutable data structures as that'll make testing easier.

Now there's certainly a better way to do it than this. You're probably best looking at what @mikera has been doing with matrices.

Or, if you want to go asynchronous, you could use Lamina or the new Plumbing/Graph library.